# How do I flatten my uneven concrete floor?

Tags: concrete, flooring, level, vinyl, self-leveling-concrete

We have an old Victorian house with a concrete floor throughout the ground floor.

The ground floor is partitioned in two by a dividing wall and french doors. From the front of the house to the doors, the floor slopes up around 7cm, but is not too uneven across the width, so we're going to put down a thick underlay and carpet.

From the french doors it slopes up a further 3cm to the middle of that area, and then is flat for the rest. Unfortunately, within that 3cm incline, it also has dips, undulations and is generally not flat across the width. Since this is the kitchen area, we don't want to put down carpet, so are looking for ways to flatten out this area of floor. We'd prefer vinyl or possibly tiles, so flatness is relatively important.

We've considered liquid latex but are worried that it will just run down towards the french doors and keep going, which we don't really want. Is there any product out there designed to smooth out undulations etc but without running so much, so we can make the slope more even?

The concrete floor is also painted, so we wondered if we'd need to strip that off or apply a primer?

Thanks for any advice you can give, folks!

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [leveling compound for concrete](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-50-lb-Rapid-Setting-Self-Leveling-Underlayment-LQ50/100192482#.UhBANE2AUkA).  That link is to one of many of Home Depot's choices for a fast setting mix which can be up to one inch thick.  The reviews say the instructions should be carefully followed; many rave about the results.  I imagine if you mucked up the application, it could be difficult to correct.  (I have only done leveling compound on top of a wood subfloor:  that was pretty easy to get right.)

Comment: thanks, I'd upvote this but I don't have the rep :) now to find something similar in the UK